# org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)

Tags: java

I am trying to do a simple http GET from url http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false& to convert address to latitude longitude but an exception was generated

Below is my sample code.

```
public void getLongitudeLatitude(String address) {
    try
    {
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(GEOCODE_REQUEST_URL);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(address))
        {
            urlBuilder.append("&address=").append(URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8"));
        }

        final GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(urlBuilder.toString());
        try
        {
            httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), getMethod.getResponseCharSet());

            int data = reader.read();
            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            while ((data = reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, data);
            }

            String result = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader("<" + writer.toString().trim()));
            Document doc = db.parse(is);

            String strLatitude = getXpathValue(doc, "//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
            System.out.println("Latitude:" + strLatitude);

            String strLongtitude = getXpathValue(doc, "//GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");
            System.out.println("Longitude:" + strLongtitude);

        } finally
        {
            getMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getXpathValue(Document doc, String strXpath) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(strXpath);
    String resultData = null;
    Object result4 = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result4;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        resultData = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    }
    return resultData;
}
```

this is the exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at com.widget.maps.LongLatService.getLongitudeLatitude(LongLatService.java:49)
at com.widget.maps.LongLatService.main(LongLatService.java:34)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Maybe the connection timed out.